# If $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $E = \{x: f(x) \geq 3\}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Prove: Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is measurable and $E = \{x: f(x) \geq 3\}$.   Show $E$ is measurable.

I saw this statement while reading in a paper and thought this might be a good proof to know. It was about Lebesgue measures which I am sort of familiar with. I did not learn this sort of proof though.

Can someone please show me how this proof would look like?

I came up with this:

$$E=f^{-1}([3,\infty))$$ 
Is this correct? Is it possible to break this down further? I am not sure since I did not learn anything about this. I am just trying this for fun. I would still like to see a proof of it.

Comment: Since you are self taught, what is your definition of i. a measurable function and ii. a measurable set?

Comment: [See this page for some MathJax basics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264).

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$E=\{x\mid f(x)\ge 3\}=f^{-1}([3,\infty))$$ where $f^{-1}$ denotes the pre-image. What is the definition of a measurable function?

Comment: @9959, so can you recognize what $[3,\infty)$ is? Also, in the definition you quoted, you didn't explain what a measurable function is. You only specified the measure spaces you are using.

Comment: @9959, I see that the definition you quoted is from wikipedia. Pick up any textbook on measure theory and read the definition of a measurable function there. You can probably prove this on your own then.

Comment: @Sanchez I thought that wikipedia is a good source to study from. That is where I learn from sometimes. I did pick a text and it said the samething.

Comment: @9959 Slightly off topic, I don't think that Wikipedia is a good place to learn math formally. It's a place for you to explore different things that could interest you. But it doesn't properly do a rigorous treatment of what you need, especially for proof questions.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ok. I find some topics of interest there though. Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph. Thanks.